# DB2/Sql grouping with condition

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I have a pretty straightforward sql query that I'm running on DB2 I-series 4 which is just performing some simple joins. The issue is that my materials table has it so that multiple material/color combos can be used on each body of work. Right now I'm getting rows of every combination but I want to consolidate so that if the value of test.materials.sequence is 2 then it creates two additional columns (if there's no sequence 2 for the combination then it would just be 0 and 0 in those columns.

THe query:

```
Select bod.code, mat.material, mat.mat_color, 
from test.skus sk
inner join test.Bodies bod on sk.body_id = bod.id
inner join test.categories prc on prc.id = sk.category_id
inner join test.skus_to_materials stm on sk.id = stm.sku_id
inner join test.materials mat on stm.mat_id = mat.id
order by prc.desc;
```

Tables:

skus

---

```
id  |  code  |  body_id  |  category_id  
------------------------------------------- 
1      12345     9912            3
2.     12346     9913            3
```

Bodies

---

```
id   |  code 
--------------------------
9912    1234-5
9913    1234-6
```

categories

---

```
id  |  category
------------------
3     Test
```

skus_to_materials

---

```
id  |  sku_id  |  mat_id  |  sequence
--------------------------------------
1     1           221         1
2     1           222         2
3     2           223         1
```

materials

---

```
id  |  material  |  mat_color 
-------------------------------
221    Fabric       black     
222    Fabric       white     
223    Leather      brown
```

This is my current result:

```
code  | material  | mat_color
-------------------------
1234-5 | Fabric    | black
1234-5 | Fabric    | white
```

This is the result I would want:

```
code | material1 | mat_color1 | material2 | mat_color2
----------------------------------------------------------
1234-5    Fabric        black      Fabric     white
1234-6    Leather       brown       0           0
```

See how 1234-6 only has the one material combination, so material2 and mat_color2 would be zeroes.

Is there a way through grouping and row-operations to achieve this?

UPDATE:

In answer to Charles' answer, I've realized some issues in one case with more data. After grouping by material, color, and desc I realized that I was getting the missing records but now ending up with this issue:

```
code   |   material1   |   color1   |  material2  |  color2
------------------------------------------------------------
1234-5      Fabric         White         0               0
1234-5      0               0          Leather         white 
1234-5      Leather         Brown        0               0
1234-5      Leather         Tan          0               0
1234-6      Fabric         Black         0               0 
1234-6      0              0           Leather         Black 
1234-7     Fabric         White          0               0
```

Comment: this would profit greatly from a dbfiddle

Comment: I dont think dbfiddle supports this dialect.

Comment: I have one going here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4zKAdw3H4hFLbfnzEeZS2/1 @jmarkmurphy it's not supporting DB2 but the current query works on both db2 and mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Charles first answer is closer. Here is what I got:

```
SELECT SK.ID SKU
      ,BOD.CODE 
      ,MAT.MATERIAL MATERIAL_1
      ,MAT.MAT_COLOR MATERIAL_2
      ,COALESCE(MAT2.MATERIAL, '0') MATERIAL_2
      ,COALESCE(MAT2.MAT_COLOR, '0') COLOR_2
FROM SKUS SK
 INNER JOIN BODIES BOD ON SK.BODY_ID = BOD.ID
 INNER JOIN CATEGORIES PRC ON PRC.ID = SK.CATEGORY_ID
 INNER JOIN SKUS_TO_MATERIALS STM ON SK.ID = STM.SKU_ID AND STM.SEQUENCE = 1
 INNER JOIN MATERIALS MAT ON STM.MAT_ID = MAT.ID
 LEFT JOIN SKUS_TO_MATERIALS STM2 ON SK.ID = STM2.SKU_ID AND STM2.SEQUENCE = 2
 LEFT JOIN MATERIALS MAT2 ON STM2.MAT_ID = MAT2.ID;
```

Resulting in:

| SKU | CODE | MATERIAL_1 | MATERIAL_2 | MATERIAL_2 | COLOR_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | BodD | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | BodB | Fabric | Black | Leather | Black |
| 3 | BodA | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | BodA | Fabric | Black | Leather | Black |
| 1 | BodA | Fabric | Black | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | BodA | Fabric | White | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | BodC | Leather | Brown | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | BodA | Leather | Brown | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | BodA | Leather | Black | 0 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4zKAdw3H4hFLbfnzEeZS2/2)

Comment: Thank you! This did what I was expecting, so it looks like that first answer was on the right track but I was relying too much on grouping as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"rows to columns" is known as "pivoting" the data.

Db2 for IBM i doesn't have a built method to pivot.  However, assuming a distinct set of values, you can hardcode it.

Something like so should do what you want:

```
Select bod.code, max(mat1.material), max(mat1.mat_color),
       max(mat2.material), max(mat2.mat_color) 
from test.skus sk
inner join test.Bodies bod on sk.body_id = bod.id
inner join test.categories prc on prc.id = sk.category_id
inner join test.skus_to_materials stm on sk.id = stm.sku_id
inner join test.materials mat1 on stm.mat_id = mat1.id
           and mat1.sequence = 1
left outer join test.materials mat2 on stm.mat_id = mat2.id
           and mat2.sequence = 2
group by bod.code
order by prc.desc;
```

**EDIT**
Ok if sequence is actually in the `skus_to_materials` then you'll need a different set of joins.  Actually in that case, I'd probably just go with a CTE based statement.

```
with allrows as (
  Select bod.code, prc.desc, stm.sequence
         , mat.material, mat.mat_color, 
    from test.skus sk
     inner join test.Bodies bod on sk.body_id = bod.id
     inner join test.categories prc on prc.id = sk.category_id
     inner join test.skus_to_materials stm on sk.id = stm.sku_id
     inner join test.materials mat on stm.mat_id = mat.id
}
select 
  code
  , max(case when sequence = 1 then material else '0' end) as material1
  , max(case when sequence = 1 then color else '0' end) as color1
  , max(case when sequence = 2 then material else '0' end) as material2
  , max(case when sequence = 2 then color else '0' end) as color2
from allRows
group by code
order by desc;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but I realized when running it: I made a huge mistake and put sequence on the materials table but it's actually in the skus_to_materials table so when I modified this to run I ended up with null values for the last 2 columns. I updated my data above

Comment: you can replace null with `COALESCE(mat2.color, '0')`

Comment: I think my issue lies in the join becuase I'm only getting null in those last two columns, even though there are instances where I should be getting values in all 4. So in my example above, I would get that first result but currently I'm not getting it because I had put sequence in the wrong table.

Comment: Thank you, that got me closer but upon getting more data I realized an issue where I was missing records which I rectified by changing the GROUP BY to group by code, material, color, desc. However, now I'm getting results like my update above. In that example, I'm seeing now that I need a group by the colors of a body code, so in my example above I should only end up with 5 rows. For code 1234-6 there are 2 rows, but they have the same color so they need to be one single row like ```1234-6 | fabric | black | leather | black``` . I accepted your answer, just curious if you have any insight

Comment: If you want the rows to pivot color and material, then you can't include them in the group by.  For 1234-6, a `group by code` is all you want.  But that would lose data from 1234-5.  For 1234-5, you need either materal3 & color3 (and 4 looks like)  or you want to `group by code, color` and just have material pivoted ( mat1, mat2)

Comment: I'd suggest doing some searches on `db2 (ibmi) pivot` for some better understaning of pivoting data in db2

Comment: thanks that makes sense, grouping only by code does work for anything that should have the 2 materials and colors, but it seems I would just want the mat1/mat2 pivot after all because in the case of 1234-5 I wouldn't want 3 and 4, I would want each to be it's own single sku

Comment: I've read a bit more on pivoting but I think I'm still missing the correct way to group by code,color and pivot the material as described. I've worked up a working fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4zKAdw3H4hFLbfnzEeZS2/0 is there anyway you could check that out and see if you can pinpoint my problem still