# Pivoting DB2 data on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to get a query together that selects products based on a combination of data (body type, materials and colors,etc.) and I've gotten close but I'm still missing a step to get exactly what I want. I've been looking more at pivoting data and I've tinkered with this query but I'm still left with this issue.

Basically, I have multiple products that only have one material and color attributed to them and they each have a unique stock keeping ID, but some of the body types will have 2 materials and colors per stock keeping unit.

My current results in this db fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u4zKAdw3H4hFLbfnzEeZS2/1
are as shown:

[image]

For the most part the results are there but BodB has the same color for both materials and should be one single row like `BoDB | Fabric | Black | Leather | Black`

So if one body code is attached to 2 different materials but the same color with sequence 1 and 2, it should be a single row effectively grouped by the body and the color (the materials wouldn't be the same, only the color. And there will only ever be up to 2 materials and colors on a given stock keeping unit

The fiddle is ready to go with these results, any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70804530/sql-pivot-table-with-multiple-pivots-on-criteria

Comment: @June7 thanks, I'm looking that over now. I know it's sql server but should be doable on DB2. I'm trying to see if the use-case is pretty much the same though

Comment: @June7 do you think a union would be a better way to achieve this?

Comment: No, I don't see how UNION would be useful.

Comment: Your fiddle example contains 5 `CREATE TABLE` statements and 1 `INSERT INTO` statement only. No SELECT showing how you use them. The example is definitely not ready to go...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I updated the link, not sure why my changes weren't showing. As you can see the example now has full create/insert statements and the query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DB2/Sql grouping with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74695618/db2-sql-grouping-with-condition) seems like it should be the same query.